# How can l save data even after refresh in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

before refresh l manage to get the observable data and display it in html however if l refresh the page l lose all the observable data, is there a way to save the state and be able to get data even after page refresh.

this is my shared service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Supplier } from '../components/selectsupplier/selectsupplierObj';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

private availablesuppliers = new BehaviorSubject<Supplier[]>(null);

constructor() { }

loadSuppliers(suppliers: Supplier[]){
  this.availablesuppliers.next(suppliers);
}

getSuppliers(): Observable<Supplier[]> {
  return this.availablesuppliers.asObservable();
  }
}
```

this is my component that gets the data and display it

```
 getSupplierID(){
 let supplierID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 return (supplierID);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
// call function on page load
this.report();
this.SupplierID = this.getSupplierID();
// console.log(typeof(this.SupplierID));
// localStorage.setItem('supplierid', this.SupplierID);

this.Auth.authStatus.subscribe(value => this.loggedIn = value);
this.shared.getSuppliers()
.pipe(
  map(suppliers =>
    // console.log("suppliers", suppliers)
    suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === this.SupplierID),take(1),
  )
)
.subscribe(response => {
  // console.log("From shared services", response);
  // console.log(this.SupplierID);
  this.supplier = response;

});
```

so on first run suppliers is populated with the data however when l refresh suppliers is returned as null.

updated code, saving data in localstorage then retrieving it to display

```
ngOnInit() {
// call function on page load
this.report();
this.SupplierID = this.getSupplierID();
// console.log(typeof(this.SupplierID));
// localStorage.setItem('supplierid', this.SupplierID);

this.Auth.authStatus.subscribe(value => this.loggedIn = value);
this.shared.getSuppliers()
.pipe(
  map(suppliers =>
    // console.log("suppliers", suppliers)
    suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID ===   this.SupplierID),take(1),
  )
)
.subscribe(response => {
  // console.log("From shared services", response);
  // console.log(this.SupplierID);
  // this.supplier = response;

  localStorage.setItem('supplierObject',  JSON.stringify(response));
  var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('supplierObject');

  this.supplier = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

  console.log("Object from localStorage", this.supplier);

});
```

}

Comment: By *refresh* if you mean page reload then yes data will be lost on browser reload, You have to save data in [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and retrieve it when component loads, But be careful you also need to delete data manually from storage in case you use localStorage.

Comment: yes on reload please check the last updated code if I'm storing it right way, though it's not working on reload l still get the (suppliers) in the map function as null.

Comment: What does `shared.getSuppliers()` do? Is it an API? If yes then you don't need to use storage anyway API is called and you get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, with your help l managed to store in localStorage and fix the bug and refactored the code as well

```
 getSupplierID(){
 let supplierID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 return (supplierID);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   //call function on page load
   this.Numeric();

   this.SupplierID = this.getSupplierID();

   //fnc call
   this.service(this.SupplierID);

   //retrive object and store in supplier
   var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('supplierObject');
   this.supplier = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
 }

 //get the observable and store in localStorage
 service(id){
   this.Auth.authStatus.subscribe(value => this.loggedIn = value);
   this.shared.getSuppliers()
   .pipe(
   map(suppliers =>
    // console.log("suppliers", suppliers)
    suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === id),
   )
 )
 .subscribe(response => {
    // console.log("From shared services", response);
    // console.log(this.SupplierID);
    // this.supplier = response;

    localStorage.setItem('supplierObject', JSON.stringify(response));
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('yourDate', response);


 getSupplierID(){
 let supplierID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
console.log("Id from route: ", supplierID)
 return supplierID; //  return (supplierID); this is a error and console.log
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    // call function on page load
    this.report();
    let id:string = this.getSupplierID() // create a variable string for id, we don't know this.SupplierID type
    localStorage.setItem('supplierid', id);
}
```

Comment: please check the last updated code if l'm storing it right way, though it's not working on reload l still get the (suppliers) in the map function as null.

Comment: you have some errors in your code `return (supplierID);` and did value of both are string and did you have them ? `let id:string = this.getSupplierID() `